# PHP with MySQL WHERE Value Range

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a variable with a certain integer. Let's call it **$num**.
What I'd like to do is to check in a table called **nums** where I have value(s) between or equal to **$num-2** and **$num+2** but **not equal** to **$num**.

Mathematically, this range would be like **[$num-2,$num[** ; **]$num,$num+2]**.

```
SELECT num FROM nums WHERE ...
```

I know this is basic querying but I'm kind of confused right now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
...
WHERE nums (BETWEEN ($num - 2) AND ($num + 2))
   AND (nums <> $num)
```

Comment: Does BETWEEN include $num-2 and $num+2? Or is it like $num-2<x and x<$num+2?

Comment: `X between A and B` is the equivalent of `(A <= X) && (X <= B)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes since it doesn't allow me to do it now.